# Placeholder error tensorflow as backend in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using keras 2.0.0 with tensorflow 1.0.1 as the backend. (python 2.7)

I am currently getting this error:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'embedding_1_input' with dtype int32
 [[Node: embedding_1_input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I am using a model.fit() from keras and feeding an nparray of integers.

```
QA_model.fit([data_quest_train,data_para_train],[data_start_idx_train,data_end_idx_train])
```

data_quest_train is passed into:

```
q_model.add(Embedding(glove_mat.shape[0],EMBED_SIZE,weights=[ glove_mat],input_length=MAX_QUEST_LENGTH,mask_zero = True,trainable=False))
```

Can any help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to answer it . If I have to guess it could be because the input data type of variables of QA_model.fit() is not in the required format

Try changing this line

```
QA_model.fit([data_quest_train,data_para_train],[data_start_idx_train,data_end_idx_train])
```

to this

```
QA_model.fit([np.asmatrix(data_quest_train),np.asmatrix(data_para_train)]
    ,[np.asmatrix(data_start_idx_train),np.asmatrix(data_end_idx_train)])
```